# Application of the theorem: A function is continuous if and only if the inverse image of any closed set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Theorem: A mapping $f$ of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed for any closed set $V$ in $Y$.

Let $f : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$. Then $f$ is obviously continuous on $(0, 1)$ but the set $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ while $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = (0, 1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Am I misunderstanding anything of the theorem or where is the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the domain of $f$ is the space $(0,1)$ with the metric induced by $\mathbb{R}$. But $(0,1)$ is closed (and open) in itself...!

In other words: the propery of being closed or open depends on the ambient space. Here the ambient space is $(0,1)$, not $\mathbb{R}$. And any space $X$ is always closed *in itself*: the chain of inclusions $X \subseteq \overline{X} \subseteq X$ shows that $\overline{X} = X$, where the closure is taken *with respect to $X$*.